# Integrating iphone apps without source code

Tags: iphone, ios

I have three iPhone apps which need to be combined as one. I don't have any source code for these three apps. I just have ipa files. Is there any way to integrate three apps into one? For example, apps called banana, orange, apple will be integrated into one main app called food. So when the user install the food, banana, orange and apple will include inside my app and user don't need to install three apps. From my food app, users can choose banana or whatever they like to see. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to integrate three apps into one?

**No.**

iOS apps can't embed other apps or even communicate with each other directly. There's no supported way to do what you're asking.

It is possible to have one app launch another *if* the target app has registered a custom URL protocol, but they'd still be separate apps. Also, it's possible to use a tool like Apple's Configurator or MDM to install several apps at once in some situations. I'm not sure if that would be useful in your case, though.

Comment: If there was a way to combine multiple apps into a new one just from the ipa files, first thing I'd do in the morning would be to release an angry birds-cut the rope-tiny wings trio to the app store :)